# SMART TV's LAN and PoE

Tags: router, lan, tv

I have a WiFi router with LAN and WAN ports but **without** PoE (no Power over Ethernet). If I connect my SMART TV (tcl led43p2us on Android TV) to router like that does TV get internet access and will be available in my local network with other devices connected to that router via WIFI?

Comment: How is PoE related to this question?

Comment: question posted because I was not sure how LAN internally work in TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any device you connect to the router with an Ethernet cable will be available to the network that the router serves. Power over Ethernet is irrelevant in this install, as most TVs don't have that capability.

PoE (Power over ethernet) is more likely to be needed where power isn't available. In this case the power to the TV will be supplied by its own AC cable.